# Use Ternary function in SQL Server to determine NULL | NOT NULL based on bit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

Say I have an input parameter to a stored procedure `@flag`

I want to filter my query based on some column `col1` being null, based on the value of this flag.

Say if `@flag = 1`, show only records with `col1 IS NULL`, if `@flag = 0`, show only records with `col1 IS NOT NULL`

My intuition would lead me to this:

```
select * 
from table1 
where col1 IS IIF(@flag = 1, NULL, NOT NULL);
```

This does compile. Is there any other concise way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even when your query compiles I doubt it will work. But you can do it with boolean `and`/`or` logic

```
select * from table1 
where (@flag = 1 and col1 IS NULL)
   or (@flag = 0 and col1 IS NOT NULL)
```